# Vertical Slider - RWD

Tags: javascript, slider

i am a newbie in programming. Just learning front end basics at the moment.
I have made a projects with udemy course called vertical sliders.

The tutorial is to make just a slider but it is not giving hints how to adjust it in case of real use in a site.
I just wonder how to adjust the code to make it possible to fit the slider in the website. so it always works how it should.

project is also shown on yt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laNpbZISwjY
my code: https://dannycee.github.io/vertical_slider/

When I have moved it to container, the slides not working as they should. The img on the right slide are working fine, but divs on the left one are not scrolling properly.
I think it has to do with last bit of javascript lines when there is line of activeSlideIndex * sliderHeight.

Comment: Paste in the code that doesn't work, also a problem reproduction would help immensely

Comment: That is the original project https://jsfiddle.net/dannycee/6nyaLh9t/2/  which I would like to use in some bigger project. The thing is when I move that slider and want to add to some other container, or adjust the size e.g. 1200px x 600px to work as a slider on a web, the slider stops working. It works only when it full screen. When dimensions are chagned the left side of the slider is dissapearing. The right side is ok. Can you advice me how it can be changed in CSS or JavaScript to make it useable in some bigger project?

Comment: here is a link to the sceleton of web with header, footer. (like if I would like to use it in some real scenario) https://jsfiddle.net/dannycee/3dx64pgj/8/ when you look in CSS: .slider-container when I changed height/width to e.g.

Comment: I also noticed that when you resize the window - the slides in some point (when window is very short) would work correcly. It clearly depends on the 'clientHeight' in inline 16 in JS, but i am not as advanced to figure out what to do here.

Comment: OK. Problem solved. I do not quite understand how, as I used chatGPT but I will analize that now.  corrected version: https://jsfiddle.net/dannycee/3dx64pgj/12/

Comment: Still not sure what sort of changes I should do to make RWD and resize the slider when changed the dimensions of the window